# How to reflect an object once it rotates past a given point in c#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a high school student trying to learn Unity and C# for a project and I'm basically a total beginner. For my project I'm creating a 2D platformer/shooter game and currently this is my code to get the player's weapon to follow the cursor:

```
        Vector3 difference = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition) - transform.position;
        float rotZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, rotZ + offset);
```

(offset is a variable I made just to mess around with how cursor positions work and it doesn't actually mean anything so just ignore it)

This works great and the weapon rotates to follow the cursor as I'd want, however when the weapon goes behind the player, the rotation means that it turns upside down. Is there some kind of way to check the current rotation and reflect the sprite for the weapon in order for it to be the right way up? Or is there some other method I'm missing which is easier.

I'm a total beginner to this so any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In the inspector for the sprite of the weapon, there is a Mirror X,Y checkbox
you could enable that when your rotation goes negative.

Hope that points you in the right direction.... pun intended

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful and I'll have a look into that, I appreciate the help very much! :)